# Excel AVERAGE function in template not working properly after upgraded jxls from 2.3.0 to 2.6.0

Tags: java, excel, jxls

Excel AVERAGE function in template only works in the first sheet not multiple sheets after upgraded jxls from 2.3.0 to 2.6.0.

In the first sheet, the average cell formula shows =AVERAGE(B12:B17). However in the second sheet or other sheets, the average cell formula shows = AVERAGE(B12, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17) which doubled the B12. It was working fine in version 2.3.0.

Is this jxls 2.6.0 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there was a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/166/excel-average-function-in-template-not) in Jxls which is now fixed on `master` branch and will be released soon with the next Jxls release (v2.7.0).